# How to fix format mismatch error in odoo?

Tags: odoo, openerp-7, odoo-8, openerp-8

I have been trying with this code

```
def onchange_date(self, cr, uid, ids, fdate, context=None):
    if fdate:
        if datetime.strptime(fdate, '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S').date() > datetime.now().date():
            return { 'value': { 'fdate': False } }
        return fdate
```

and I am getting this error

> ValueError: time data '2015-07-25 06:24:46' does not match format '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S'

Answer (score 2):

Replace this code

```
if datetime.strptime(fdate, '%Y %m %d %H:%M:%S').date() > datetime.now().date():
```

with to

```
if datetime.strptime(fdate, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").date() > datetime.now().date():
```

Comment: Thanks Odedra. it worked like a charm. one more question, how can i prevent the user from selecting the future as well as past date ?  now the above line is to restrict from selecting the future date..

Comment: can you help me on one small issue... I had kept 12 hour format in the language settings, and i am getting this error                                     ValueError: time data '2015-07-26 19:35:02' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S'

Comment: yes, i have tried,, will there be any effect in the code if the time format is changed from 24 hour to 12 hour format in Odoo language settings ?

Comment: if it's work than please accept answer with check on right symbol near by up/down vote. Thank you.